# Subpanel grounding add ground

Tags: grounding, subpanel

I have a 100 amp subpanel and is fed with a #2-3 AWG so i have no grounding just a neutral. Instead of replacing the wire because it is still good, can i just run a seperate ground wire #8 from the main panel with the #2 and enter into the sub. It would save alot of time and money.

Comment: #8 is good if copper, not not if aluminum. I'm assuming the "wire" in question is a cable (containing multiple conductors). I can't find a requirement for the feeder EGC to be part of the cable if one is used, so running it alongside the cable looks completely valid.

Comment: The feeder shall "Include or provide" an EGC (215.6), but a feeder is defined as all the circuit conductors between the service equipment and the final branch branch-circuit overcurrent device. I cant even find rules about it needing to follow the same path, but inspects may not like that so I'd advise running alongside the feeder cable if feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to run the ground wire in addition to having a ground rod. They do different jobs.

What size and type of wire is it?

If it's aluminum #2 (90A) or copper #3 (100A) then you can use an 8 AWG copper ground (or an insulated 6 AWG aluminum ground).

If it is copper #2, that is 115A wire and you will need a 6 AWG copper ground or a 4 AWG aluminum ground.  Even if you're feeding it with a 90-100A breaker, if you make the wire larger than it needs to be, you must also make the ground larger in proportion.

Answer (score 0):

Probably...Yes:   If the sub-panel is in an attached structure w/the main panel, then simply running the ground is all you need to do.  You still  have to isolate the neutrals from the ground in the sub, ie: float the neutral, as in don't bond the neutral to the ground in the sub. If in a detached structure, the above rule still applies but you'll need to add a couple of ground rods at least 6' apart and connect to the ground buss bar in the sub.